# Python, word frequency of each sentences for summarization

Tags: python, text, nlp, summarization

I'm trying graph based text summarization.

```
sentences_rank_frek=[]
for sentence in copy_sent:
    for word in sentence:
        if word in freq:
            sentences_rank_frek[sentence]+=freq[copy_sent[sentence][word]]
```

This code is given error: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
I can show this freq[copy_sent[0][1]] = 4

Comment: You can't access the list `sentences_rank_frek` if your `sentence` is not an integer.

Comment: sentence is integer

Comment: What about `copy_sent[sentence][word]`?

Comment: copy_sent is a text list.// copy_sent[0][1] = "sale" // copy_sent[0]= First sentence in text

Comment: Are you saying then that you are trying to access the list `freq` with a text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what is the type of your `sentence` variable while trying to do this access `sentences_rank_frek[sentence]`. I'm guessing....it's a sentence so it must be a string or list of strings. You're trying to access an index in a list using a string.

You might want your `sentences_rank_frek=[]` to be a dictionary instead of an array.

Comment: {#frequency
for sentence in copy_sent:
    for word in sentence:
        if word in freq:
            freq[word]=freq[word]+1
        else :
            freq[word]=1}

Comment: I can compute frequency each words

Comment: Could you maybe clearly list out the different data types of each variable?